# Parse Aurora Slow Query Logs pt-query-digest

Tags: amazon-aurora

I'm trying to use pt-query-digest to aggregate slow query logs from Aurora stored in Cloudwatch. I use the awslogs tool to grab them and write them to a file, it looks like they are formatted wrong, even after I strip out the host information. A traditional slow query has the following as a header before the query:

```
# Time: 2017-08-04T19:24:50.630232Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   236
# Schema:   Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 11.003017  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 57
```

where as the logs from Cloudwatch look like this:

```
# Time: 2021-02-16T20:35:10.179940Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []  Id:   236
# Query_time: 5.290956  Lock_time: 0.001651 Rows_sent: 8  Rows_examined: 1858252
SET timestamp=1613507710;
```

has anyone found a way to use pt-query-deigest to consume Aurora logs?